# Laravel ErrorException when trying to access model attribute

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, model, attributes

I have $formas_pagos variable loaded with FormasPago model data. When i iterate trough $formas_pagos, if i do a dump and die, i got everything ok:

[image: damp an die of formas_pagos variable]

But if i want to access, for example, to 'anio' attribute doing `$forma_pago->anio;` , i got this ErrorException

[image: ErrorException screenshot]

If i do this

```
$attributes = $forma_pago->getAttributes();
$attributes['anio'];
```

inside the foreach, i can get the 'anio' attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my model had composite key. I switched it to have an auto increment id pk, and solved my problem